# MAAS node OS auto install - failed to retrieve preseed configuration file

Tags: maas

MAAS server is up and running with 4 nodes. Nodes have commissioned and are in Ready state

I'm running into an issue while automating OS install using standard default preseed file.

Node starts fine from MAAS webconsole but it couldn't retrieve the preseed file from MASS server using standard URL 
(http://192.168.x.x/MAAS/metadata/latest/by-id/node-/?op=get_preseed).
since the node couldn't download the preseed file, the installation falls back to non automated mode.

Clocks are in sync and the URL works fine from MAAS server web browser.

Comment: Facing the same issue when using juju with one of my nodes. 2 nodes allocated by juju. But one node stuck on pending due to http failure to get preseed file. why this happen only with that node ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using juju to deploy the nodes, then you first need to "Allocate" the nodes to a MAAS user in order for them to deploy.

Comment: And indeed vice-versa :)

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. the problem was node was getting Ip from the other DHCP server. which is on another network.